# Why is openGL blocking the UI?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

**Update #1** I've implemented a queue of PBOs that I loop through to try and help reduce UI lag.  Basically I bind to a PBO, call `glReadPixels`, set up a fence object, and wait for that object to be signaled.

All the while I'm loading in more pixels into other PBOs via `glReadPixels`.  Once the sync object becomes signaled, I attempt to `glMapBufferRange` on the signaled PBO.  However this is still blocking the UI.

Is there a way I can get these calls to run on a separate renderer?

---

I'm writing an application to take screen data off of a phone, and turn a series of images into a video.  My issue is that I no matter what I do, the openGL calls block the UI thread.

Below I've posted the code I'm using to read pixels from the screen, and then map them back into a ByteBuffer that I can manipulate later on.

My application takes in a GLSurface that I queue up events to, however queuing up events to this passed GLSurface blocks the UI.

I've attempted creating a new GLSurface view with the following: `GLSurfaceView mGLSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(mContext);`  However all of the events that are called through `queueevent` never get processed.  Why is that?

```
private void screenScrape() {

    sync = 0;

    //read pixels from frame buffer into PBO (GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER)
    mGLSurfaceView.queueEvent(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //generate and bind buffer ID
            GLES30.glGenBuffers(1, pboIds);
            checkGlError("Gen Buffers");

            GLES30.glBindBuffer(GLES30.GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pboIds.get(0));
            checkGlError("Bind Buffers");

            //creates and initializes data store for PBO.  Any pre-existing data store is deleted
            GLES30.glBufferData(GLES30.GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, (mWidth * mHeight * 4), null, GLES30.GL_STATIC_READ);
            checkGlError("Buffer Data");

            glReadPixelsPBO(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, GLES30.GL_RGBA, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
            checkGlError("Read Pixels");
            long afterTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

            sync = GLES30.glFenceSync(GLES30.GL_SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0);
        }
    });

    //map PBO data into client address space
    mGLSurfaceView.queueEvent(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            int result = GLES30.glClientWaitSync(sync, GLES30.GL_SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT, 15000000);
            Log.d(TAG, "GL Client Wait Sync Result = " + result);

            //read pixels from PBO into a byte buffer for processing.  Unmap buffer for use in next pass
            mapBuffer = ((ByteBuffer) GLES30.glMapBufferRange(GLES30.GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0, 4 * mWidth * mHeight, GLES30.GL_MAP_READ_BIT)).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            checkGlError("Map Buffer");

            GLES30.glUnmapBuffer(GLES30.GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER);
            checkGlError("Unmap Buffer");



            flipBuffer(mapBuffer);
            mapBuffer.clear();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will be confused about is that `glReadPixels PBO` is meant to be an async call, but in all of these cases, it actually blocks the render thread for a long time. That's why you have those problems.

> Anyway, instead of `glReadPixelsPBO` -> `glReadPixelsFBO`

Comment: To make sure I'm understanding you correctly, you're suggest that instead of calling `glReadPixelsPBO` I should be calling `glReadPixels`.  Is that correct?

Comment: No, you should use `glReadPixelsFBO(...)`

Comment: I'm not positive that I can use framebuffers for this task in my project.

Alternatively, is there a way I can get the glReadPixels / glMapBufferRage to run on a different renderer so that they don't block the main one?

I've since implemented a buffer queue for glReadPixels calls, then I setup a series of fence objects that trigger glMapBufferRange once glReadPixels has returned.  This doesn't improve my run time at all though.

Comment: http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2012/presentations/S0356-GTC2012-Texture-Transfers.pdf
from page 12, maybe you will find something helpful. Also https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glFenceSync.xhtml. http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/opengl-es-glreadpixels-blocking-on-pbo-on-android/38122/view.html